# Linux software for drawing 3D diagrams

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-rec, drawing, 3d

My professor has asked me to draw a certain diagram for a poster which he wants to present at a conference. Which program on Ubuntu gets this done?

My image/drawing consists of the following:

1. *x*, *y*, and *z* axes
2. Particles. These are to be represented as colored balls
3. The graph of a bell curve in 3D

Comment: The other question asks for applications for windows. This question should not be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Ah, you're right though @Nifle. smilingbuddha - if you feel that this is not a duplicate, you should say so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think gnuplot may suit your purposes. Since gnuplot has no gui the learning curve can be fairly steep but this link might get you started.

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pm3d.html